# PHP require_once fatal error in OpenShift - maybe a filepath issue but I'm stumped

Tags: php, openshift

I'm writing in PHP for an OpenShift app and am stumped by a fatal error when I try to require another PHP script. I've tried numerous permutations of filepath, but none of them resolve the problem.

The PHP file appears to exist: I can SSH into my app and navigate to it at `/var/lib/openshift/5357ba345973cac7c400021d/app-root/repo/lib/dothis.php`

My current PHP code:

**`require_once ($_ENV['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'] . 'lib/dothis.php');`**

Previous unsuccessful attempts:

1 `set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $_ENV['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR']);
require_once ('lib/dothis.php');`

2 `require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/lib/dothis.php');`

3 `include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/lib/dothis.php');`

4 `require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'lib/dothis.php');`

5 `require (realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/lib/dothis.php');`

6 `require (dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib/dothis.php');`

For my current php code, the `rhc tail` log gives this:

**[Fri Apr 25 12:41:22 2014] [error] [client 127.3.140.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/lib/openshift/5357ba345973cac7c400021d/app-root/runtime/repo/lib/dothis.php' include_path='.:/var/lib/openshift/5357ba345973cac7c400021d/app-root/runtime/repo/lib:/var/lib/openshift/5357ba345973cac7c400021d/app-root/runtime/repo/libs:/var/lib/openshift/5357ba345973cac7c400021d/app-root/runtime/repo/libraries:/var/lib/openshift/5357ba345973cac7c400021d/app-root/runtime/repo/src:/var/lib/openshift/5357ba345973cac7c400021d/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor:/var/lib/openshift/5357ba345973cac7c400021d/app-root/runtime/repo/vendors:/var/lib/openshift/5357ba345973cac7c400021d/php/phplib/pear/pear/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/lib/openshift/5357ba345973cac7c400021d/app-root/runtime/repo/process.php on line 221**

Comment: I notice that the path in your error message does not match the path in your SSH statement. I'd got with `dirname(__FILE__)` and adjust that path until you get what you need.

Comment: Did you try `require 'lib/dothis.php';`?

Answer (score 0):

Please, cross check your file location in question!

OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR refers to $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/app-root/***runtime***/repo/

You may, instead, use $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR and add rest of the path!!

Refer:
https://www.openshift.com/developers/openshift-environment-variables